# How to deal with 'drive-by moderation' in small tags

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that perfectly good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757766/how-to-wrap-a-morph-into-a-window-in-pharo-v3) in subjects where there are few experts get closed as being too broad by people without any obvious subject matter expertise. Flagging that behavior doesn't help, as moderators have the same problem. In this case, the number of subject matter experts that can reopen questions is so low that casting reopen votes doesn't help (especially as that just leads to more drive-by moderation).

The result is that SO is currently not a good site for questions on these subjects (and as a result does't attract the existing subject matter experts).

Comment: The question you refer to is in my opinion really broad. Why is it not in yours?

Comment: @juergend it appears to be similar to a "How can I display a JComponent in a window?" in Java, which has the straightforward answer "Create a JFrame and set your component as the content pane".

Comment: It is a very specific question, in the context of pharo, smalltalk and morphic. It is not a very difficult question, and there are a few ways to answer it, but not many

Comment: @immibis: And I think this broad answer does not help someone asking this broad question.

Comment: @juergend Given that the asker accepted the answer, I would say it does.

Comment: It is a typical beginner question indeed which the documentation does not handle

Comment: No wonder it got closed. Still got an reopen from me, as this is indeed difficult to google. But I also took the liberty of downvoting both the coarse question and the super shallow answer (which boils down to just five words). One-liners don't raise the overall site quality, and certainly don't benefit small tags, even when they compensate for lackluster language docs.

Comment: Asking here will probably solve the problem for the question referenced, and is also not a really good solution in general. I am still interested in how to make SO a better place for small tags too. Should there be different thresholds for them?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is most certainly not the normal outcome in [tags] on the long tail of SO.  There are normally far too few users that look at such questions and vote to get such a question to progress to closure.  None of the questions I ever vote to close in, say, the [c++-cli] or [com] tag that I frequent ever get closed.  Makes it a pretty useless exercise, really.

This question was different, a diamond moderator stepped in and Andrew has hammer rights.  Surely because somebody flagged the question, the way to alert moderators about content they normally never look at.  You can perhaps blame him for not knowing anything about [smalltalk] but his "too broad" detector is very well tuned.  Of course moderators are not subject experts.  If you want to dispute it then just flag the question yourself and ask another moderator to look at it.  Having that flag dismissed is a distinct possibility however, this is not great Q+A.

Comment: Happened twice already. " declined - The question really needs to be fleshed out. Including the code for the rectangle morph would help a lot." The lack of subject matter expertise shows.

Comment: Well, I saw that coming.  I don't get the point of the complaint, if you think this Q+A is ideal and the answer is perfect then why does it matter that nobody can post another less-than-ideal answer?

Comment: It may be the best in this specific context, there are a few others that are worthwhile to look at in similar situations. Explaining those contexts is what brings value (at least to me)